# c# - DataGridView RowsRemoved event not working

Tags: c#, datagridview, event-handling, row

I want to remove the current selected row from my dataGridView1 when the user presses the DEL button on the keyboard.

Here is my code so far

```
    // Remove selected row
    private void DeleteRow()
    {
        try
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index);
            MessageBox.Show("Row removed");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("row remove EX");
            return;
        }
    }

    // Event when user presses DEL button on keyboard
    private void dataGridView1_RowsRemoved(object sender, DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventArgs e)
    {
        DeleteRow();
    }
```

The application removes the row but the `DeleteRow()` function never executes, since I never see the `Row removed` message. Am I missing something?

**EDIT**: Updated code

Comment: And the event is subscribed? dataGridView1.RowsRemoved += dataGridView1_RowsRemoved; ?

Comment: In the `Form1.Designer.cs` it is set as `this.dataGridView1.RowsRemoved += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_RowsRemoved);`. When replacing it with your text, it's still the same..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what is visible by the code you posted, you call DeleteRow() from RowsRemoved event handler.

But the RowsRemoved will not execute until a row is deleted. And if it will execute it will directly again delete another row - if there is one or throw an exception.

Please try:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowsRemoved(object sender, DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("row removed").
    }
```

Try to understand what you have coded by setting a debugging breakpoint in DeleteRow(). Currently your application is like DeleteRow->RowRemovedEventHandler->DeleteRow

So your code to remove the row is executed twice.

Comment: Updated the code in `DeleteRow()` when I hit DEL it throws the exception message `row remove EX`

Comment: @Dean Please see my updated answer. And please be more descriptive next time with your question. Include source code and describe what exactly does happen. This will save a lot of time.